# terraform kubernetes-alpha provider fails with 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am trying to use kubernetes-alpha provider in my terraform config. I am using it to apply app-crd.yaml to manage my resources as a group.

```
kubectl apply -f "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/marketplace-k8s-app-tools/master/crd/app-crd.yaml"
```

I converted this yaml file into a tf files using https://github.com/jrhouston/tfk8s tool

I am using kubernetes-alpha provider to apply this tf file as manifest

my tf configurations looks like below.

provider.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes-alpha = {
      source = "localdomain/provider/kubernetes-alpha"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes-alpha" {
  host                   = "https://${var.endpoint}"
  token                  = var.token
  cluster_ca_certificate = var.cluster_ca_certificate
  server_side_planning   = true
}
```

app_crd.tf

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "customresourcedefinition_applications_app_k8s_io" {
  provider = kubernetes-alpha

  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    "kind"       = "CustomResourceDefinition"
    "metadata" = {
      "creationTimestamp" = null
      "labels" = {
        "controller-tools.k8s.io" = "1.0"
      }
      "name" = "applications.app.k8s.io"
    }
    "spec" = {
      "group" = "app.k8s.io"
      "names" = {
        "kind"   = "Application"
        "plural" = "applications"
.
.
.
    "status" = {
      "acceptedNames" = {
        "kind"   = ""
        "plural" = ""
      }
      "conditions"     = []
      "storedVersions" = []
    }
  }
}
```

When I try terraform plan I get a 415 Unsupported

```
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: -----------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: 2020/08/27 15:14:57 [DEBUG] Kubernetes API Response Details:
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: ---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: HTTP/2.0 415 Unsupported Media Type
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Content-Length: 165
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Audit-Id: 537f3df0-f9b8-4f57-a3ce-6afacc383bc4
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Content-Type: application/json
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 22:14:57 GMT
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: {
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "kind": "Status",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "apiVersion": "v1",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "metadata": {},
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "status": "Failure",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "message": "415: Unsupported Media Type",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "reason": "UnsupportedMediaType",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "details": {},
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "code": 415
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: }
```

The API Request looks like below

```
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: -----------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: 2020/08/27 15:14:57 [DEBUG] Kubernetes API Request Details:
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: ---[ REQUEST ]---------------------------------------
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: PATCH /apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions/app
lications.app.k8s.io?dryRun=All&fieldManager=Terraform HTTP/1.1
plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Host: <REDACTED>
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: User-Agent: terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha/v0.0.0 (darwin/amd64)
kubernetes/$Format
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Content-Length: 2957
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Accept: application/json
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Content-Type: application/apply-patch+yaml
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: Accept-Encoding: gzip
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha: {
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "apiVersion": "apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "kind": "CustomResourceDefinition",
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  "metadata": {
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:   "creationTimestamp": null,
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:   "labels": {
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:    "controller-tools.k8s.io": "1.0"
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:   },
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:   "name": "applications.app.k8s.io"
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-kubernetes-alpha:  },
.
.
.
```

I manually installed the plugin as discussed here [terraform manually installed plugin fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531360/terraform-manually-installed-plugin-fails/)

Am I missing any config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on GKE cluster with version 1.15 which doesn't have server side support. Upgrading my cluster to 1.6 fixed this issue